# Try to collect all data with function for categorization and send it with Ajax JSON

Tags: php

I have a table for multi-level categorization with category_id , name, parent_id and sort_order. I want to select all categories and show them in tree view. When use it without sending with JSON it work but when send it with JSON show only parent categories without sub categories.

My code is:

```
function categoryTree($parent_id = 0, $sub_mark = ''){
    global $connection;
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM ws_categories WHERE parent_id = :parent_id ORDER BY sort_order ASC, name ASC';
    $statement = $connection->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute(['parent_id' => $parent_id]);
    $filtered_rows = $statement->rowCount();
        $array = array();
        while ($row = $statement->fetch()) {
                $sub_array = array();
                $sub_array[] = $sub_mark.$row['name'];
                $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="update" id="'.$row["category_id"].'" class="btn btn-info btn-sm update"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button>';
                categoryTree($row['category_id'], $sub_mark.'---');
                $array[] = $sub_array;
        }
        return $array;
}

$data = categoryTree();

$output = array(
    "draw"              =>  intval($_POST["draw"]),
    "recordsTotal"      =>  $filtered_rows,
    "recordsFiltered"   =>  get_total_all_records(),
    "data"              =>  $data
);
echo json_encode($output);
```

Make it work without JSON and see:

```
Cat1
Cat2
---SubCat1
------SubSubCat1
Cat3
```

but when use with above code shows only:

```
Cat1
Cat2
Cat3
```

I think that `categoryTree($row['category_id'], $sub_mark.'---');` not working in the WHILE loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) the result of recursive function with your current one.

```
$sub_array = array();
$sub_array[] = $sub_mark.$row['name'];
$sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="update" id="'.$row["category_id"].'" class="btn btn-info btn-sm update"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button>';
$array[] = $sub_array;
$array = array_merge($array, categoryTree($row['category_id'], $sub_mark.'---'));
```